# Excel Data Validation Formula Failing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to have a dropdown with writing permissions based on the content of the cell next to it (so that it is not possible to chose something if the partner cell contains specific characters).

So far this is working:

```
=IF(AND($G4<>"Keep";$G4<>"Cancel");Hilfsblatt!B$2:B$4;)
```

Now I would like to include "" as a criteria as well. However, excel gives me an error for that:

```
=IF(AND($G4<>"";$G4<>"Keep";$G4<>"Cancel");Hilfsblatt!B$2:B$4;)
```

HOWEVER this one is working

```
=IF(AND($G4<>" ";$G4<>"Keep";$G4<>"Cancel");Hilfsblatt!B$2:B$4;)
```

Why cant I use the argument ""?
The error I am getting is: **The source must be a separate list or a reference to a single row or column.** However, I do not understand how this is related to my changes?

edit: Sorry, excel language was german. I hope the translation is correct now.

Comment: I suppose G4 holds a formula, so using `Isblank(` is not an option?

Comment: G4 is regularly empty (active data validation as well) the goal is if a user puts in information he is only able to include further information if necessary (specific selection in G4)
Isblank( is not working as well > same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's because you leave your `False` condition in your `IF(` blank. This can't be done if the type is a list, as a list is not provided. This will throw an error if the formula resolves to `False`. If adding the third condition makes the statement `False` you will get this error seemingly out of the blue, even though your condition seems perfectly valid.

To get around this, you can add a reference to an empty cell as your `False` condition, to circumvent the error:

```
=IF(AND($G4<>"";$G4<>"Keep";$G4<>"Cancel");Hilfsblatt!B$2:B$4;A1)
```

Where `A1` is a blank cell of your choice.

Comment: such a stupid mistake haha. I thought using formulas within data validation - false means no input is allowed I guess I was wrong about that. Thank you very much for pointing it out for me!